# Hash table not populating in C

Tags: c, hashtable

I am learning hash tables and having a difficult time getting my program to work. I am reading from a file line by line to get the data being input into the hash table. I compile with no errors or warnings but my output is not what I was expecting. Instead of a table populated with the data from the file I get

```
      0      S
1     ----
2     ----
3     ----
etc
```

The 0 S is not supposed to be there and the whole hash table is empty. I have no idea where the 0 S came from and I cannot figure out why the hash table is not populating correctly. I have been looking around some sites and forums but haven't found anything that seems to be related to my problem. Anything to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>
#define T_SIZE 128
#define MAX_NAME_SIZE 16


typedef struct
{
  char name[MAX_NAME_SIZE];
} nameIn;

nameIn * hTable[T_SIZE];

unsigned int hashFunc(char *pName)
{
  unsigned int HA = ((abs(pName[4] + pName[5]) / 3) + (abs(pName[5]) / pow(2, 16)) + (abs(pName[2])));

  return HA;
}

void initialTable()
{
  //sets all entries in hash table to empty (NULL)
  for(int i = 0; i < T_SIZE; i++)
  {
    hTable[i] = NULL;
  }
}

void printTable()
{
  for(int i = 0; i < T_SIZE; i++)
  {
    if(hTable[i] == NULL)
    {
      printf("%i\t----\n", i);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("\t%i\t%s\n", i, hTable[i]->name);
    }
    
  }
}

bool insert(nameIn *n)
{
  if(n == NULL)
  {
    return false;
  }

  int indx = hashFunc(n->name);

  if(hTable[indx] != NULL)
  {
    return false;
  }

  hTable[indx] = n;

  return true;
}

int main()
{
  //starts the program with an empty hash table
  initialTable();

  //prints hash table
  //printTable();

  //opens file we are reading names from for the hash table
  FILE *fileIn = fopen("2057357.txt", "r");
  //creates a string to hold the contents of each line of the file
  char line[MAX_NAME_SIZE];
  //creates counter for number of entries in the table
  int eCount = 0;
  //creates collision counter
  int collisionCount = 0;

  while(fscanf(fileIn, "%s", line) != EOF && eCount < (T_SIZE / 2))
  {
    //increments entry counter
    eCount += 1;
    nameIn inName = {.name = *line};
    
    insert(&inName);
    
  }
  printTable();
}
```

If I don't read from file and do this instead it works fine.

```
nameIn abc = {.name = "abc"};
nameIn hdg = {.name = "hdg"};
nameIn nfo = {.name = "nfo"};

insert(&abc);
insert(&hdg);
insert(&nfo);

printTable();
```

Comment: `nameIn inName = {.name = *line};` That looks wrong. `*line` is only the first character of the string. Need to use `strcpy` instead. Of just `fscanf` straight into `inName`.

Comment: Is that a new C thing, or wishful thinking?

Comment: I tried changing it to strcpy(iName, line); nameIn inName = {.name = iName}; That gave me a slightly better result where the first element in the hash table is S instead of 0 S followed by empty element one and so on. The rest of the hash table is still empty though

Comment: `insert(&inName);` is wrong. You are inserting a pointer to a local variable. Local variables cease to exist as soon as control leaves the block, pointers to those become invalid. You need to learn about dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: So I should pass the pointer to the insert method and then process it?

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: Your hash function is a bit incongruent. `pow(2, 16) == 65536`.   If you integer divide a char by 65536 you'll get 0 (always). So your hash doesn't depend on `pname[5]` (in the second sumand). You can take that off.  Normal is to multiply values, not divide them.  I don't understand the reasons that made you to prefer dividing the numbers.

Comment: A simpler hash, like `HA = pName[1] * 17; HA = HA * 17 + pName[2] * 23; HA = HA * 19 +  pName[3] * 331; HA = HA * 13 +  pName[4] * 47; HA = HA *3 +  pName[5]; return HA` (you still need to check that the input string has all those characters or you'll get bad things) would be better than the one you use.